# Configuring OkHttp to perform POST api call - and accept untrusted certificate

Tags: authentication, certificate, okhttp

I am very new to SO, API and certificates and hoping someone can guide me. This is my first post!

I have an ASP.net website secured with a 'lets encrypt' SSL certificate.

I have an android studio app that makes a POST call to that website using basic authentication and, theoretically, a TrustManager that accepts all certificates to allow it through to the website.

Trouble is it gets rejected.

With SSL turned off on the website, the call works fine.
With SSL turned on, despite theoretically using an OkHttp client that is set to trust all certs, it returns a 500 error - I can get little more info back from the server.

I have done a load of googling, and all techniques seem to use the same process.

( I also appreciate the security issues of trusting all certs, but am using it to just encrypt the username/password. I have additional security on the api itself as I know unique identifiers for all devices that need to use the api and can reject any that arent registered).

Any help anyone can give would be gratefully received, and if I am doing something amazingly dim do let me know!  I do wonder if my whole approach to this is wrong!

The code is as follows (took me a little while to get it formatted so it was readable and ok for SO)

```
    
public class OkHttpExample {
    public void main() {
    // Create OkHttp client
    try {
        // Create a trust manager that does not validate certificate chains
        TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = new TrustManager[]{
        new X509TrustManager() {
        @Override
        public void checkClientTrusted(java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) {}
        @Override
        public void checkServerTrusted(java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) {}
        @Override
        public java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
            return new java.security.cert.X509Certificate[]{};
       }
     }
    };
    // Install the trust manager
    SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
    sslContext.init(null, trustAllCerts, new java.security.SecureRandom());
    SSLSocketFactory sslSocketFactory = sslContext.getSocketFactory();
    // Create OkHttpClient with the custom SSL socket factory
    OkHttpClient.Builder newBuilder = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
    newBuilder.sslSocketFactory(sslContext.getSocketFactory(), (X509TrustManager) trustAllCerts[0]);
    newBuilder.hostnameVerifier((hostname, session) -> true);
    OkHttpClient newClient = newBuilder.build();
    String credentials = Credentials.basic(username, password);
    url = "http://testsite.co.uk/api/create.php";
    urlparam = "";
    RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(JSON, buildJson());
    request = new Request.Builder()
       .url(url)
       .header("Authorization", credentials)
       .post(body)
       //.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")
       .build();
    // Make the request
    try (Response response = newClient.newCall(request).execute()) {
       if (!response.isSuccessful()) {
          throw new IOException("Unexpected response code: " + response);
         }
       // Handle response data
       String responseBody = response.body().string();
       Log.d("response", responseBody.toString());
       System.out.println("Response: " + responseBody);
    } catch (IOException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
    }  
  } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | KeyManagementException e) {
    throw new RuntimeException("Failed to create OkHttpClient", e);
     }
  }
}
```